# No OS select menu when starting up my HP laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, hp

I am new to Ubuntu and thought it looked better than Windows 8.1

I have installed Ubuntu onto my laptop but as soon as I had installed it, it restarted and went straight to Windows booting up.

I did some research and most said to change my BIOS settings and I think I have to change the UEFI settings to Legacy Mode and change the the boot order to use the USB drive first.

However, whenever installing, it will continue to go to Windows unless I press <kbd>F9</kbd> and choose Ubuntu. But Ubuntu will not always load, but instead will freeze on a plain black screen with no cursor and I have to remove the battery and replace it after a few seconds. It will then go back to Windows and the screen will flash sometimes.

I have managed to get onto Ubuntu once after rebooting the laptop 4 or 5 times. But I just hope this can be fixed as the time it did work it was awesome and I want it to become my preferred system.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are one of two things has happened (maybe both):

- You installed Ubuntu incorrectly, in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode when Windows was installed in EFI/UEFI mode. In almost all cases, it's best to install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows. Doing otherwise can create symptoms like those you describe. There have been a number of recent questions about this, but my Web search turned up [this older one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216627/problems-dualbooting-ubuntu-because-of-uefi) and not the newer ones. It's still valid, though.
- Your firmware is broken. Some machines just don't like dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu. There are various workarounds to such problems. The least intrusive is to use `bcdedit` in Windows or `bcfg` in an EFI shell; but you may need to rename boot loader filenames. Again, Google is giving me older questions and answers, but two that I believe are still valid is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi) and [this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394199/removing-ubuntu-from-uefi-bios-menu)

If you need more help, please post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file generated by the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (in the `boot-info-script` in Ubuntu, IIRC).